# SQL Server stored procedure order when two or more values conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database

I'm building a SQL Server stored procedure (on Sql Azure) I'm able to generate the data for the requirement but I'm not able to make the order, I have no idea of how to do it.

The following is the query result at the moment (this is random data with the necessary columns)

```
File    | Description   | DateOfFile | OrderOfLoad | BatchID
--------+---------------+------------+-------------+---------    
ABC.DOC | a description | 2016-07-12 |      2      | 10
DEF.PDF | a description | 2016-07-10 |      4      |  6
GHI.DOC | a description | 2016-07-12 |      2      |  3
XYZ.PDF | a description | 2016-07-10 |      1      |  7
WWW.XLS | a description | 2016-05-01 |      5      | 15
```

First I have to order by date from most recent first (`order by DateOfFile DESC`), but just in case there are two or more files with the same date (AAAAMMDD) the order decides like this: the last `BatchId` number and the first `OrderOfLoad` number (just if there are conflict with the date of two or more files), so, for the example here the order would be

1. ABC.DOC ...(the other part of the record)
2. GHI.DOC ...
3. XYZ.PDF ...
4. DEF.PDF ...
5. WWW.XLS ...

I would appreciate if any of you can guide me the way of accomplish with this, a good one for not affect performance, I was thinking to insert this on a temporal table and then make some loop (preferably not cursor), but for now I have no ideas.

Thanks guys.

Comment: What does your query look like? You can have more than 1 column in the Order By, e.g. `Order By DateOfFile DESC, OrderOfLoad` etc

Comment: Also, if you have two files of the same name, do you want to display both or only the latest one?

Comment: Hi @christiandev, the order looks like the Sergio order, but in my case BatchId and OrderOfLoad have to appears just in case when there are two or more same dates, if there are no dates conflict the order it just by date.

Comment: See my answer, I actually partition by file and date and only take the latest one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this in your ORDER BY clause:

```
ORDER BY DateOfFile DESC, BatchId DESC, OrderOfLoad
```

Comment: Hi @sergio, my order looks like yours, but in my case BatchId and OrderOfLoad have to appears just in case when there are two or more same dates, if there are no dates conflict the order it just by date.

Comment: @DanyG That `ORDER BY` will do exactly what you want.  If there is only one value for a particular `DateOfFile` then there is nothing else to order so the other clauses are irrelevant.

Comment: @Sergio Yes sr, as simple as that, It's working well as you suggest, my error was that I had some others stuffs (not relevant for this) on my query that made this simple order not to work, but after fixing it works perfect. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment earlier, you can have multiple columns in the Order by, and the query will prioritise from left to right...

So, in your case, if you changed the statement to `ORDER BY DateOfFile DESC, BatchId DESC, OrderOfLoad` it would sort by `DateOfFile`, then `BatchId` and finally `OrderOfLoad`.

However, this will show the same filename if it was loaded twice in the same day.  If you want to show the latest file for that day, you could use `Row_Number()`...

```
WITH    cteFiles
          AS (
              SELECT    [File]
                       ,[Description]
                       ,DateOfFile
                       ,OrderOfLoad
                       ,BatchID
                       ,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [file], DateOfFile 
                                      ORDER BY DateOfFile DESC, BatchId DESC, OrderOfLoad)
              FROM      tablename
             )
    SELECT  [File]
           ,[Description]
           ,DateOfFile
           ,OrderOfLoad
           ,BatchID
    WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Hi @christiandev, thanks for your help and your time, I was able to resolve it with the Sergio query, but this helps me for another SP that I need for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your File Log Table something is missing.

As per `Sergio` suggestion the query will give you the output. In order to make it more robust, you can create a `batchID` unique and that is related to `BatchDate` so that you can query to get our output more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for your time.